# How to remove strange class code from navigation?

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently made some custom changes in Wordpress theme, and included custom links. I inserted this code into footer:

```
</div><!-- .main -->
<?php
if ( ! is_page_template( 'full-width.php' ) ) {
get_sidebar( 'primary' );
}
?>
</div><!-- .overflow-container -->

<footer id="site-footer" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
<h6>
    <a href="/disclaimer/">DISCLAMER</a> |  <a href="/privacy-     policy/">PRIVACY POLICY</a> |  <a href="/contact/">CONTACT</a>
</h6>
<?php
if ( get_bloginfo( 'description' ) ) {
    echo '<span class="tagline">' . esc_html( get_bloginfo( "description" )   ) . '</span>';
}
?>
<div class="design-credit">
    <span>

    </span>
</div>
</footer>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And now when open some of pages listed in footer ,some [strange CSS](http://www.deepakmaddila.com/disclaimer/) code appear in page navigation. So how to remove that code from navigation, and keep only page name like [here](http://www.deepakmaddila.com/sample-page/)

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: I inserted all footer.php code.. Can you check better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add html in title attribute;

```
<span title="<span class=&quot;riyad_title&quot;>Disclaimer</span>"> &lt;span class="riyad_title"&gt;Disclaimer&lt;/span&gt;</span>
```

I think that problem lies in breadcrumb and you messed with functions.php

**EDIT:**

Thats WP Hide Title plugin conflict, disable it

https://yootheme.com/support/question/97319

Comment: please post template.php of that theme. disclaimer is using it

Comment: also functions.php

Comment: if you remove that code that you added does it work.

Comment: Currently is added that code. Check in footer what show when your code is added. Not worked.

Comment: are you using Breadcrumb Trail Plugin or any other breadcrumb plugin, that seems to conflict, It has nothing to do with code in footer.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Thanks !!! Will mark your answer as correct. Thanks